# "Could not locate package metadata" error after clicking the configure button of a desktop effect KDE

Tags: json, xml, qt, kde-plasma

I've been developing a config menu for [this kwin desktop effect](https://github.com/kde-yyds/kwin4_effects_foldpopups/) and I am getting a popup, instead of the UI of the configure menu, and it says:

```
Could not locate package metadata
```

[image: error]

Here are my directory structure, ui, config and metadata files since they will be important later.

Directory structure

```bash
kwin4_effects_foldpopups
├── contents
│   ├── code
│   │   └── main.js
│   ├── config
│   │   └── main.xml
│   └── ui
│       └── config.ui
└── metadata.json
```

ui/config.ui

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>FoldPopupsEffectConfig</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="FoldPopupsEffectConfig">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>338</width>
    <height>89</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Fold Popups Effect Configuration</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="grid_layout">
   <item row="0" column="0">
    <widget class="QLabel" name="duration_label">
     <property name="text">
      <string>Animation Duration</string>
     </property>
     <property name="alignment">
      <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="0" column="1">
    <widget class="QSpinBox" name="kcfg_Duration">
     <property name="suffix">
      <string> milliseconds</string>
     </property>
     <property name="minimum">
      <number>300</number>
     </property>
     <property name="maximum">
      <number>5000</number>
     </property>
     <property name="singleStep">
      <number>10</number>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="1" column="0">
    <widget class="QLabel" name="behavior_label">
     <property name="text">
      <string>Animation Behavior</string>
     </property>
     <property name="alignment">
      <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="1" column="1">
    <widget class="QLabel" name="tbc_label">
     <property name="text">
      <string>To be continued</string ><!-- TODO: Add behaviour options here -->
     </property>
     <property name="alignment">
      <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

config/main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kcfg xmlns="http://www.kde.org/standards/kcfg/1.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.kde.org/standards/kcfg/1.0 http://www.kde.org/standards/kcfg/1.0/kcfg.xsd">
  <kcfgfile name=""/>
  <group name="">
    <entry name="Duration" type="UInt">
      <default>300</default>
    </entry>
  </group>
</kcfg>
```

metadata.json

```json
{
    "KPackageStructure": "KWin/Effect",
    "KPlugin": {
        "Name": "Fold Popups",
        "Name[zh_CN]": "气泡折叠动画",
        "Description": "Make popups smoothly fold in and out when they are shown or hidden",
        "Comment[zh_CN]": "气泡信息显示/隐藏时呈现折叠过渡动画",
        "Category": "Appearance",
        "Authors": [
            {
                "Email": "kde-yyds@qq.com",
                "Name": "kde-yyds"
            }
        ],
        "Icon": "preferences-system-windows-effect-fadingpopups",
        "Id": "kwin4_effects_foldpopups",
        "License": "GPL",
        "Version": "1.0",
        "EnabledByDefault": "true",
        "ServiceTypes": ["KWin/Effect"]
    },
    "Type": "Service",
    "X-KDE-Ordering": "60",
    "X-KDE-PluginKeyword": "kwin4_effects_foldpopups",
    "X-KDE-ConfigModule": "kwin/effects/configs/kcm_kwin4_genericscripted",
    "X-KWin-Config-TranslationDomain": "kwin_effects",
    "X-Plasma-API": "javascript",
    "X-Plasma-MainScript": "code/main.js",
    "X-KDE-ParentApp": "kwin"
}
```

I've tried reading the documentation and doing what it says to do, copying metadata files of other desktop effects that had a working configure menu and modifying them but it didn't work.

I even modified metadata files of other and realized when `Id` parameter is different than the directory name, other effects also gave the same error. But what's really weird is my `Id` is exactly the same as the directory name of the effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took some digging after I ran into the same problem.

The very short version is that you need to rename your effects plugin.

It must start with, exactly, `kwin4_effect_`, otherwise genericscriptedconfig will decide that you're a script instead of a scripted event, and look in `.local/config/kwin/scripts/` instead of `.local/config/kwin/effects/`

I have yet to find documentation that explicitly covers this, I found it by digging into the code.